# Ag-grid cell editing stops while double clicking on a header has children

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have an issue with stop editing when i double click on a header has children columns.

Reproduction

Double click on a cell to edit.

Double click on a header (Athlete Details or Sports Results).

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Lc4UUzgcWZSXOu04)

```
 headerName: 'Athlete Details',
 headerName: 'Sports Results',
```

The double click on the header child "Athlete" do not stop editing, but the double click on the header "Athlete Details" stop editing.

**Expected**

The double click on the header "Athlete Details" do not stop editing.

Comment: DId you check properly? In the link that you provided, it is working as expected.

Comment: Expected: The double click on the header "Athlete Details" doesn't stop editing.
I tried with firefox and chrome.
There's a solution with creating a component for the header, but i prefer to block the double click to work fine as the header "Athlete"